# How to get Host IP address in the Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, python-requests

I want to pass my host IP address to my template in Django.
Should I get it from the request then pass it to the template?
If, yes how can I get this variable from the request in the view?

Answer (score 2):

```
# view 
def get_client_ip(request):
    x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    if x_forwarded_for:
        ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
    else:
        ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    return render(request,'app/base.html',{'ip':ip})
```

**base.html:**

```
IP Address: {{ip}}
```